# Android - Your content must have a ExpandableListView whose id attribute is

Tags: android

I am trying to make an ExpandableListView but whenever I run it my app crashes with:

> 09-14 14:08:36.060  16792-16792/imp.translator.diana.lang
> E/AndroidRuntime﹕
>
> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>
> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{imp.translator.diana.lang/imp.translator.diana.lang.Record}:
> java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a
> ExpandableListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'
>
> at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)

This is a part of my main activity:

```
public class Record extends ExpandableListActivity{
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_record);

    ExpandableListView expandableList = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    } 
}
```

and my xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ExpandableListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:groupIndicator="@null" />

</LinearLayout>
```

I have tried changing it to `android:id="@android:id/list"` but it says `cannot resolve symbol list`

What else is there to do? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: This is because you extended from `ExpandableListActivity` (does this type of Activity even exist?), instead of from `Activity`. Also, in your layout, you're missing the LinearLayout heading (copy/paste typo?).

Comment: changed it. Works perfectly now. Thank you very much!